# Handling single page application url and django url

Tags: django, vue.js, single-page-application, vuejs2

I have a single page application created in Vue.js that utilizes the HTML5 History Mode for routing, and the html file is served with Django.

The **urls.py** of django is like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
]
```

And **views.home**:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Consider the following scenario:

1. User visits the home page (i.e., `/`)

Since, the home page responds with required index.html for the Single page Vuejs app, it works like its supposed to.

2. From there the user navigates to the about page (i.e., `/username/12`).

Its still working fine, as its navigating with the Vue router.

3. Now, the user refreshes the page.

Since there's no `/username/12` in the **urls.py** patterns, it will show **Page not found (404)**.

Now, I could provide another pattern in **urls.py** to catch all pattern in the last order as this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^.*$', views.home),
]
```

But other urls like the media or static urls will also point to the same *catch all pattern regex*. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The catch-all URL is the way to go. This won't affect media or static, as they are not served by Django in production.

Answer (score 28):

> I have a similar problem.
>
> How can I use vue-router and django rest
>   framework **the same time**?

This is my solution to this problem. Hope it helps you.

Expected results：

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/       <-- TeamplateView index.html using vue
http://127.0.0.1:8000/course <-- vue-router
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api    <-- rest framework
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin  <-- django admin
```

and I try this and it works!

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

> The order is important, 
>   `url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),` 
>   is the last one

and this is my vue router

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [{
      path: '/courses',
      component: CourseSet
    }, {
      path: '/',
      component: hello
    }]
})
```

[My project on GitHub](https://github.com/bllli/ReverseCourse/commit/37e3fc4084d89020ec8a6852370cf9ba99d24d73)

Comment: This wont work with /admin (without trailing slash). The path will be catched by '^.*$' and slash wont be appended with middleware to check for /admin/. The reason it worked for you is probably because of http cache. So negative look-ahead (?!admin) is the only option

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov I am facing same issue that you have mentioned. I can use /accounts/ redirects properly but /accounts redirect is being catched by the catch all url pattern. Can you please show me how to define accounts url pattern in urls.py?

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov No issues. I was able to do it like '^(?!accounts)(?!api)(?!blablabla).*$'
Thanks for the direction. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

Since you have mentioned "single page":

1. The server is supposed to serve just one page the `index.html` (or whatever else you would like to call it).
2. The server and the web application (front-end) code would communicate via api calls, such that the server provides resources and the web-app takes care of using that resource.
3. In case of a missing resource, the server still must not respond with a separate page, it should still respond with a message that the web-app can use.

> I have a single page application created in Vue.js that utilizes the HTML5 History Mode for routing

I believe you are using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/), which simulates the single-page app to be a full-featured, multi-page application.

---

You may want to take a look at [this](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/backend.html) and [this](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html), but the above holds true for a single page application.

---

You shared your urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
  url(r'^.*$', views.home),
]
```

> But other urls like the media or static urls will also point to the same catch all pattern regex. How can I solve this problem?

1. A way you can manage that would be either by, serving on a route other than `'/'` like mentioned above for `/app`.

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
     url(r'^.*$/app', views.home),
   ]
   ```

   and in your router.js file:

   ```
   new Router({
     mode: 'History',
     base: '/app'
     routes: [
       {
         path: '/',
         name: 'name',
         component: ComponentName
       }
     ]
   })
   ```
2. Or prefixing the purpose served by the urls like

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^api/admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^api/api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
     url(r'^.*$', views.home),
     url(r'^.*$/assets', your-static-assets) 
   ]
   ```

Comment: What exactly is `your-static-assets`? Is that a function in `views.py`?

Comment: Nice work! I changed it to `url(r'^app/.*$', views.home)` for option number 1 which works perfect for me.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using VueJS router enabled history mode with Django 2.x by this way:

From app urls.py you need to `repath` your frontend url like this:

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="application.html"), name="app", ),
    # ... rest of your urls
]

urlpatterns += [
    re_path('^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="application.html")),
]
```

Now history mode working smoothly!

```
http://sample.com/#/users/login/
```

Become:

```
http://sample.com/users/login/
```

Comment: Works on django 4.x and Vue 3, thanks

Comment: thank you, man! 
digging for weeks thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by using the negative look-ahead regex, so basically anything inside `(?!ignore1|ignore2)` will be ignored.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^(?!admin|api-token-auth|static).*$', views.home),
]
```

Note: I tried not including `admin` and `api-token-auth` inside the negative look-ahead and it didn't work for me, it will still route path that starts with `admin` to the `views.home`, not sure why as according to my understanding, django should match the earlier ones first.

Answer (score 0):

Since index.html is templated (a dynamic page) because it's served from your views instead of static, this becomes a bit weird.

For production, definitely use nginx or apache to serve the static content in a similar fashion.

For development, this is what I would do:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
]

# Serve your static media (regex matches *.*)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns.append(url(r'(?P<path>.*\..*)$', serve))

# Serve your single page app in every other case
urlpatterns.append(url(r'^.*$', views.home))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided above by @billi works fine, up to a point. My problem is that for my SPA I want (need?) to use the Vue <*router-view*> and <*router-link*> system. But the router.js maps paths to Vue components, and some of my paths are to Django views via Django urls.py - for example, this will result in a blank page if navigating to /api/places from the Vue router nav, but will resolve correctly to a Django if refreshed.

Ideas?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Django
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^api/places$', views.PlaceList.as_view()),

    # catchall to Vue single page app
    url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='myapp/spa.html'), name='home'),
]
```

**router.js**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {path: '/search', component: Search},
    {path: '/about', component: About},
    {path: '/', component: Home},
    {path: '/api/places', }
  ]
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
    <router-link to="/search">Search</router-link> ::
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> ::
    <router-link to="/api/places">Place API</router-link> ::
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find anything for this? If I change my Django url for the template view from url to re_url, it seems to resolve but it blocks file upload functionality from working properly.

Comment: nope, sorry. stopped trying to use Vue for that app

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone still looking for the solution.
I build Django Rest API and Vue front totally in a stand alone way. Then when i tried to  put the dist folder items in static files of Django and tried to server through gunicorn and NGINX I just could not get the spa working.
Finally did this and very surprisingly it works.

Basically,

> ***forward error page to the index.html*** of Vue.

Here's my NGINX config:

```
location /static/ {
    root /root/bdn/bdn/server/;
}

location /media/ {
    root /root/bdn/bdn/server/;
}

location ^~ /admin/ { # Define routes to be directed to backend as proxy
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

location ^~ /api/ { # Define routes to be directed to backend as proxy
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

location ^~ /api-auth/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}

location ^~ /{
    root /root/bdn/bdn/server/templates/;
    index index.html;
}

error_page 404 /;  # THIS IS WHAT IT CAME DOWN TO AFTER HOURS AND HOURS OF SEARCHING
```