# Render dist file (of Vuejs) through Django

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-templates

Trying to render vue js build (index.html) in Django its working fine but the problem is that when i give any route to that url than i get page not found from vue.

This working fine

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='whatever'),
```

And this is not, giving page not found error of vue

```
url(r'^website/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='whatever'),
```

[image]

Comment: How do you render your vue instance?

Comment: i am directly calling template of vue js in urls.py please check this 
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='whatever'),

Comment: Try `url(r'^website/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='whatever'),`

Comment: Not working, still page not found:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I got a solution to the problem you have to set the default route in your router to set it redirection to the specific path

code for your router.js in vue project

```
new Router({
  mode: 'History',
  base: '/app'
  routes: [
   {
     path: '/',
     name: 'name',
     component: ComponentName
   }
  ]
})
```

and also mention the same URL name in you API in Django

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
  url(r'^.*$/app', views.home),
]
```

for more detailed conversation refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42865029/9596853)