# How to let Django see files under dist/static generated by Vue.js compilation?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, webpack

I'd like to know how to specify static directory for Django in the following case.

- I don't use Django template at all (I don't use `{% static ... %}` in html file).
- vue-cli generates outputs under `dist/`, which is not in the scope of Django project,
  and I don't like to change this.
- In `index.html`, `bundle.js` is loaded by `<link href="static/js/bundle.js">`
- Would like to let Django see `index.html` and all js files under `static/js` dir.

**Directory tree**

```
root
├── vue_proj
│      └── dist
│           ├── index.html <- SPA, and no Django template in this.
│           └── static <- I wouldd like to let Django see this dir!
│                 └── js
│                      └── bundle.js
└── django_proj <- I executed "django-admin startproject project" here.
       └── project <- I executed "django-admin startapp app" here.
             ├── manage.py
             ├── app 
             └── project
                   ├── settings.py <- What should I do here?
```

So far I could let Django see `dist/index.html` by setting TEMPLATES parameter
to `../vue_proj/dist`.
I tried the follows but resulted in failure of loading js files...

```
STATIC_ROOT = '../vue-proj/dist'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    BASE_DIR.parent / "vue-proj/dist/static'",
]
```

static root is use for production it will collect all your css and js from static folder to  static root dir.

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent / "static_cdn"
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit you saved my life! At the same time, I could find the way to make Vue.js work with Vue router history-mode by refering to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864641/handling-single-page-application-url-and-django-url :)

Comment: Hello @Pythoner glad to hear that you got solution. (: