# Django - page not found with VueJS

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm trying to create a SPA with Vue in my Django project, so that Django handles only authentication templates and the rest of the frontend is entirely Vue rendered by webpack-loader, so it's Django rendering the Vue app. I'm doing this in order not to lose the benefits of having authentication handled entirely by Django.

So everything below `/accounts/` will be handled by Django templates rendered by django views, while everything below `/app/` will be handled by the Vue application.

I have the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Some standard django templates url here for authentication..
    # ...
    # The Vue app:
    path('app/', views.vueApp, name='vueApp'),
]
```

So when the user navigates to `mysite.com/app`, Vue will handle the whole frontend as a SPA with its routes:

```
//main.js
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: '/app',
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/test1', component: testcomponent },
    { path: '/test2', component: test2component }
  ]
})
```

The problem with my code, is that if i click on a link to `test1` or to `test2` from **inside** the Vue app, i will get redirected to `testcomponent` (`mysite.com/app/test1`) and `test2component` (`mysite.com/app/test2`); instead, if i open my browser and i navigate directly to `mysite.com/app/test1` or `mysite.com/app/test2` i will get a Page Not Found error by Django, i think because Django thinks i'm trying to reach a standard Django url, while instead i'm trying to reach an URL handled by my Vue app.

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864641/handling-single-page-application-url-and-django-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with this, you need a catch-all route to ensure that you capture everything after that `/` in your url as well. Otherwise it looks like your url is not a match. You need something like this (if you're using regex to match):

```
path('app/?.*$', views.vueApp, name='vueApp'),
```

This should match everything that starts with `app/` and has other stuff after it as well. You don't care about capturing that stuff with django bc the vue router will handle it from that point.

ETA:
If you're NOT using regex, I *think* you can use this format to accept whatever comes after the slash:

```
path('app/<path:rest_of_path>', views.vueApp, name='vueApp'),
```